# UISlider thumb not moving

Tags: thumbnails, move, uislider

The slider thumb is locked. I can't move it except programatically. I can't figure out why.

```
- (void)revealOrHideSlideBar:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer*) sender
{
    for (UIView* subview in [self.view subviews])
        if ([subview isMemberOfClass:[UIImageView class]])
            [[subview subviews] makeObjectsPerformSelector: @selector(removeFromSuperview)];
    UIImageView* imageview = (UIImageView*) [sender view];
    UISlider* slider = [[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, imageview.bounds.size.height, imageview.bounds.size.width, 10)];
    slider.minimumValue = -5;
    slider.maximumValue = 5;
    [slider setThumbImage:[Utils imageWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"sliderThumb"] scaledToSize:CGSizeMake(10, 10)] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    // todo: set slider value from imageView properties
    [imageview addSubview:slider];
}
```

imageWithImage is just a method that resizes the thumb image.

Comment: it seems to be something regarding superview-subview ... my slider is a subview of a subview of the self.view ... for the code above: the [sender view] (or imageView) is a subview of self.view , and slider is a subview of the imageView. If i add make the slider a subview of self.view directly, the slider works. But i don't want to do that.

Comment: Got it...seems that a subview isn't responsive if it's bounds are outside its direct superview (parent view). A get around solution would be to put the two views in a third view witch will be the parent view for both of them.